# C# quiz calculate percentage

Tags: c#

I have a quiz that have many questions and 5 possibilities of answers.

Lets take one question,it has follow answers:

```
148 - Good
5 - N/A
268 - Great
5 - Regular
11 - Bad
```

These are numbers collected directly from database.Now i need to show it as percentage.i.E:

```
Great - 45%
Good - 40
```

[..]
and so on

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post more details; this doesn't make sense.

Comment: 268/(148+268+5+5+11) = 61.33%

Comment: Are you asking a C# or SQL question?  If C# what does the data structure look like?  If SQL do you only have the aggregate sum or the details and what does the table look like?

Comment: I suppose you don't have 5 variable, but some kind of data structure? Do elaborate on the subject.

Comment: I didnt implement nothing yet.I need logic to implement it later.

Comment: @user257234 - No he is not kidding you. Your question is poorly written / worded.

Comment: @user257234 - Ian is right, your question doesn't make much sense, and isn't easy to understand, specifically with a wrong example. He isn't kidding. No Sir. We take these thing very seriously.

Comment: Well, you said that you have "collected directly from database" - into what? What is the structure? Are you looking for another query, or manipulation of your databale/entity/other data structure?

Comment: No kobi,i just need the logic to implement percentage.

Comment: No it isnt.Im just a junior programmer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int na = 5;
int good = 148;
int great = 268;
int regular = 5;
int bad = 11;
int sum = na + good + great + regular + bad;

naPercent = getPercent(na,sum);

float getPercent(int value, int sum)
{
  return (value*100.0)/sum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a programming question, it is a math question.  The percentage of each item is equal to the number of that item divided by the total number.  In your example, the total number is 148+5+268+5+11 = 437.  Great = 268 / 437 = 61.327%

Comment: Agreed not sure why this is here.  User provided no details on language or implementation.  I mean this "c#" question could be easily expressed as an basic math - word problem.  "You have 145 answers marked great and 278 answered marked good ..... what % of your total answers are great?"

Answer (score 1):

total count for the answer / total count for all answers to this question combined * 100

Comment: Note that this one will always return an integer (in case that count and total count are integers).

Comment: It's not source code so... how would it return anything? :P